# x32debug exception access violation

Tags: windows, debugging

I am trying to open a file in a program called DavkaWriter. Most of the files generated from this program I can open. I am facing an issue with a certain file. The software just crashes. I opened DavkaWriter in x32_debugger. I am attaching a screenshot of what looks like the issue. I am running this software on Windows 10 64 bit. The exact error code is "First chance exception on 005004C2 (C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)!" The picture is attached as a link. This may be an amateur question but I have never debugged before. Thank you for your help!

[First chance exception on 005004C2 (C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM0U2.png)

Comment: is this your program? Do you have the source code?

Comment: Hi! No it is not my program. It is a commercial program. I do not have the source code.

Comment: if you have never debugged before then you probably are not going to get very far, binary ionly debugging is very tricky. You should contact the vendor

Comment: I already attempted to contact them. They aren't very helpful

Comment: Would you take a look at the file if I can upload it here. Would really appreciate it but I understand if you can't